# how to fetch data from three or more tables?

Tags: mysql

I have to find out the output as class name,number of students on each class and average marks in class? My both tables are-

```
 CREATE TABLE class(Fields_ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20));
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(30,'FIRST');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(31,'SECOND');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(32,'THIRD');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(33,'FOURTH');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(34,'FIFTH');
SELECT * FROM class;

CREATE TABLE student(Fields_ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20));
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(30,'JYOTI');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(31,'KIRTI');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(32,'YOGITA');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(33,'RASHMI');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(34,'NUPUR');
SELECT * FROM student;

CREATE TABLE Marks(Fields_ID INT, Student_ID INT NOT NULL,marks INT NOT NULL);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (30,40,100);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (31,41,88);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (32,42,72);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (33,43,33);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (34,44,15);
SELECT * FROM Marks;
```

I was trying to return the required out from the following code but i was unable to form the logic for average marks. Any idea how to do it.I am a beginner in MySql so I am unable to find out the problem.

```
SELECT class.Name , COUNT(student.name),Marks.marks
From class INNER JOIN student INNER JOIN marks
    ON class.Fields_ID=student.Fields_ID=Marks.Fields_ID
GROUP BY class.Name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT class.Name , COUNT(student.name),avg(Marks.marks) as average_mark
  From class 
  INNER JOIN student on class.Fields_ID = student.Fields_ID
  INNER JOIN marks  on marks.Fields_ID = student.Fields_ID
  GROUP BY class.Name;
```

Comment: It is making an column of avg marks but does not return any values in   any of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  SELECT c.Name , COUNT(s.name),m.marks
  From class c
  INNER JOIN student s on c.Fields_ID = s.Fields_ID
  INNER JOIN Marks m on m.Fields_ID = s.Fields_ID
  GROUP BY c.Name
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01a1b/2)

- you can add `order by m.marks` if you want order by marks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT class.Name, COUNT(student.Name), avg(Marks.marks)
FROM class 
JOIN student 
ON class.Fields_ID = student.Fields_ID
JOIN Marks
ON student.Student_ID = Marks.Student_ID
GROUP BY class.Name;
```

I have made some changes to your tables and sample data, because I belief this is more logical. I have added **Student_ID** field to the table **student**. Because otherwise you don't have a way to uniquely identify the rows in you table student. At present you are using `Fields_ID` however, I think this in incorrect. You want to know the marks from the students and not from the fields.

**Sample data**

```
 CREATE TABLE class(Fields_ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20));
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(30,'FIRST');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(31,'SECOND');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(32,'THIRD');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(33,'FOURTH');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(34,'FIFTH');

CREATE TABLE student(Student_ID INT NOT NULL, Fields_ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20));
        INSERT INTO student(Student_ID, Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(40, 30,'JYOTI');
        INSERT INTO student(Student_ID, Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(41, 31,'KIRTI');
        INSERT INTO student(Student_ID,Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(42, 32,'YOGITA');
        INSERT INTO student(Student_ID,Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(43, 33,'RASHMI');
        INSERT INTO student(Student_ID,Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(44, 34,'NUPUR');


CREATE TABLE Marks(Fields_ID INT, Student_ID INT NOT NULL,marks INT NOT NULL);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (30,40,100);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (31,41,88);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (32,42,72);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (33,43,33);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (34,44,15);
```

[SQLFIDDLE Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0021c/1)

**EDIT :**

I think that at present your table `Marks` will have a `PRIMARY KEY` called `Fields_ID`. This will not work, because there will be more marks than for each field. I would therefore recommend changing the `PRIMARY KEY` in table `marks` to `Marks_ID int auto_increment`. You could if you want to not create a seprate key to identify the rows and use a compiste key ( PK: `Student_ID`,`Fields_ID`). BTW don't forget to change the primary key of student.

This the table structure with sample data including the primary keys:

```
 CREATE TABLE class(Fields_ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(20));
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(30,'FIRST');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(31,'SECOND');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(32,'THIRD');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(33,'FOURTH');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(34,'FIFTH');

CREATE TABLE student(Student_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Fields_ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20));
        INSERT INTO student(Student_ID, Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(40, 30,'JYOTI');
        INSERT INTO student(Student_ID, Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(41, 31,'KIRTI');
        INSERT INTO student(Student_ID,Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(42, 32,'YOGITA');
        INSERT INTO student(Student_ID,Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(43, 33,'RASHMI');
        INSERT INTO student(Student_ID,Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(44, 34,'NUPUR');


CREATE TABLE Marks(Marks_ID INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, Fields_ID INT, Student_ID INT NOT NULL,marks INT NOT NULL) ;
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (30,40,100);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (31,41,88);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (32,42,72);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (33,43,33);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (34,44,15);
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/576cc/1)